# Displaying multiple threads data on the screen approach

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I am making my own crawler for my master degree thesis. I want to display multiple threads variables on the screen while running for monitoring. I tried this approach but after a while screen becomes unresponsive.

```
    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate()
{
    listBox1.Items[irWhichMainTask] = srMainSiteId + " : " + srMainSiteURL + " : processed " + irLocalProcessedLinkCount + " : max thread count " + irLocalThreadCount + " : active thread count " + irActiveThreadCount;
}));
```

Alright this is becoming unresponsive when even there is 20 threads running after a while. So seems like using listbox is not a good approach to display data on the screen. What else  can I use ?

C# 4.0, WPF

Comment: I would try the same thing with, for ex., richtextbox to see whether it is a listbox problem

Comment: I checked richtextbox and i don't see any way to make it line based. I mean at listbox i am editing always same line so able to follow threads. But richtextbox i don't see anyway of it.

Comment: Of course, Just use it for debugging purposes(use AppendText for ex) to see whether your screen becomes unresponsive or not. (To be able to see yourcode or the Listbox is the reason of the problem)

Comment: I think richtextbox can be line based by adding "\n" to the string. But My guess is you will need to clear the listbox periodically if it's getting a ton of new data constantly. But you'd have to be adding a lot of items. Listbox's can hold (i think) 32K items.

Comment: Yes i can add new lines but it causes a lot of mess since each thread completes its job at different times. It is the nature of web crawling :) Currently it is being displayed like this : http://img705.imageshack.us/img705/5535/listbox.png

Comment: **I don't say to use richtextbox as a final solution, Just use it for debugging purposes to see that what is wrong, your code or ListBox? Think this is as a way to track down the problem**

Comment: Have you considered that 20 threads running at the same time might be a problem?  How many CPU on this machine?   I use a 4 CPU machine for some CPU intensive data parsing and then load the parsed results into SQL.  I found more than 2 threads I got worse performance.  The OS wants a thead/CPU and so does SQL.  Do you think SQL server spawns 20 threads on single CPU machine?

Comment: I have core i7 2600k - 8 cores. With overclock running at 4.5 GHZ. And yes very cpu consuming. Single application consuming 50% of total cpu power :)

Comment: You should definitely consider controlling the number of total threads running to save yourself from CPU hangs, because Windows won't do it for you. I suggest writing a queue manager over that which monitors the count of threads executed to keep that in check.

Comment: Actually i am running more than 20 threads. Those 20 are main threads for every product selling website. Each main threads have also sub threads like at least 5. I am setting the number. Well cpu does not get 100% so i suppose it should not cause problem. I suppose database queries are slowing down the application.

Comment: Just because you are not getting 100% CPU does not mean you do not have too many threads.  If too many threads are contending for CPU then a they cannot efficiently get to the CPU.  You are using additional threads to segment work. The thread count need to be optimized and the number will be less than 100 (like 6-12).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try creating an observable collection for your thread statuses. Then bind the listbox to this collection.

EDIT:

```
// Define a data context
public class MyContext
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Values { get; set; }
}
```

You can do the following in xaml but my wpf is a little rusty. I put this into form load.

```
// Create an instance of your context
var myContext = new MyContext();
myContext.Values = new ObservableCollection<string>();

// Set up a binding between your collection and the 'Items' property of the listbox
Binding b = new Binding();
b.Source = myContext;
b.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
b.Path = new PropertyPath("Values");
ListBox1.SetBinding(ListBox.ItemsSourceProperty, b);

// Add values to the collection - these will automatically end up in the listbox
myContext.Values.Add("New item");
myContext.Values.Add("Other new item");

// You can change values too
myContext.Values[0] = "This has changed";
```

Comment: can you please give more details ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx

An observable collection will fire an event when the contents is changed. This means when you databind to the listbox, you won't need to worry about updating the UI. Just update this collection and databinding will take care of the rest.

Comment: Thanks for answer but it gave an error : This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread.

Comment: That's unfortunate. if you use the BeginInvoke to update the collection do you end up with your original problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that ListBox is causing problem.  You are creating a lot of temp strings on the UI thread.  Best practice is to use String.Format().  Also, build the string on the crawl thread.  You are also consing a new Action on every call.

```
var status = String.Format("{0} : {1} : processed {2} ...", srMainSiteId, srMainSiteUrl, ...)
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action) delegate()
  {
  listBox1.Items[irWhichMainTask] = status;
  });
```

Comment: now this new action thing may impact. What is the different between saying new action or action ?

Comment: Mine is just a cast to keep the the compiler happy (no run-time penalty).  Yours is creating a new Action object.  Also, you concating of strings is really inefficient.

Comment: Does this string thing really matters ? I never saw any performance problem because of temp strings.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG You have a performance issue and getting help and yet you repeatedly discount the input or ask for more details rather than learn it and try it.   Show some effort or I am going to down vote you.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option would be to use Task Scheduler and have it marshal the data back to the UI thread.

Comment: Please more details. I don't understand anything from this.

Comment: Here is a link.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/06/18/parallel-programming-task-schedulers-and-synchronization-context.aspx

Comment: This is what i am doing. What is different at that article ? I also read that one.

Comment: You are using Task Scheduler to do the processing in the background which manages the threads better.  It keeps the UI responsive.